# Kubernetes persistence volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes

I'm installing Grafana in Kubernetes using HELM and installed using below command

```
helm upgrade --install my-grafana grafana/loki-stack  --set grafana.enabled=true,prometheus.enabled=true,prometheus.alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false,prometheus.server.persistentVolume.enabled=false -n monitoring
```

Everything looks good except loki-prometheus-server pod and loki-prometheus-node-exporter pods. They are in Pending state. If I describe the pod it gives this error

```
Events:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│   Type     Reason             Age                    From                Message                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│   ----     ------             ----                   ----                -------                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│   Warning  FailedScheduling   48m                    default-scheduler   0/6 nodes are available: 6 persistentvolumeclaim "loki-prometheus-server" not found. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.                                          │
│   Warning  FailedScheduling   17s (x10 over 42m)     default-scheduler   0/6 nodes are available: 6 persistentvolumeclaim "loki-prometheus-server" not found. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.                                          │
│   Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  2m49s (x271 over 48m)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up: 3 persistentvolumeclaim "loki-prometheus-server" not found
```

But the PVC exists. If I do `kubectl get pvc` it will show loki-prometheus-server

```
kubectl get pvc 
NAME                     STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
loki-prometheus-server   Bound    pvc-ce598aa9-ff7d-428f-83c8-ac2bea07f417   6Gi        RWO            azurefile      39m
```

Comment: What version of K8s do you use? Also, can you share `k get pvc loki-prometheus-server -o yaml`?

Comment: Kubernetes version is 1.25.5

Comment: Oh my bad. PVC was in default namespace